# How to deal with the situation that template is rendered but the data is not ready?

Tags: meteor

In client startup I subscribe to something:

```
Meteor.publish("Roles", function(){
  return Roles.find();
});

Meteor.startup(function() {
  if(Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.subscribe('Roles');
  }
});
```

And roles template:

```
Template.roles.helper(function() {
  allRoles: function() {
    return Roles.find().fetch();
  }
})

<template name="roles">
  <div>
    {{#with allRoles}}
      <label>{{> role }}</label>
  </div>
</template>
```

The problem is sometime `roles` template is rendered before the `Roles` is ready.

How to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the subscribe on the template and then use the `Template.subscriptionReady` helper to create a conditional to show a loading panel whilst your subscription is being loaded as follows:

```
Template.roles.onCreated(function () {
  this.subscribe("Roles");
});

Template.roles.helper(function() {
  allRoles: function() {
    return Roles.find().fetch();
  }
})

<template name="roles">
  <div>
    {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
      {{#with allRoles}}
      <label>{{> role }}</label>
    {{else}}
      Loading...
    {{/if}}
  </div>
</template>
```

This replaces your other subscription and these subscriptions can be added to each onCreated method for each template to have subscriptions per template.

Comment: this works, but I'll use this roles template in several places(urls), so every time switch between these urls, the roles template will be created and subscribe to `Roles`, and the server will publish `Roles` everytime. But the Roles Collection only needs published once because the content of roles is fixed. How can I solve this?

Comment: How are you doing your routes?

Comment: use `iron-router`, but I dont want to use `waitOn`, because in every routes I must write the same `waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe('Roles') ;}`.

Comment: You don't have to write it on every route, you can do this: `Router.configure({
  waitOn: function(){
  Meteor.subscribe('roles');
 }
});`

Comment: What happens if I switch routes? Will server publish `Roles` each time?

Comment: I'm not 100%, but I expect not. I'm assuming Iron router is smart enough to not re-subscribe, because the `Router.configure` is specifically for setting up options on all routes. The template specific subscriptions are there specifically so they will be automatically removed when the template is destroyed so that behaviour is also expected

Comment: And I have Router.configure and several routerController, eventually I have to write same code...

Answer (score 0):

There are some common ways of dealing with it. You can use a guard or make use of iron router's `waitOn` function. With a guard you only return data from the helper if you're getting any results:

```
allRoles: function() {
    var roles = Roles.find();
    //explicit version
    if (roles.count()) return roles

    //implicitly works as well here because you're returning null when there are no results
    return roles
}
```

You don't need the fetch() in this case, because #with works with a cursor. If you run into a situation where you need to fetch first because you're returning partial data, check that there are results first and only then return them.

You can also use iron router's [waitOn](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#the-waiton-option) Option if you're using this as part of a route.